# i have an issue on the loading images on my custom collectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

i have `tableViews` which contains each row folder(Album Image) which i save images to it in the document directory 
when i select the each folder i enter in the custom `collectionView` which contains all the images in the document directory and display it on the cells my issue is collectionView very slow loading the images in the `collectionViewCells` it take 5 to 7 seconds when loading all the images in the `collectionViewCells`

the following below my code in `viewWillAppear`:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

            setEditing(false, animated: true)
            arrayOfImagesFromDocumentDirectory = []
            dictionaryOfGetImageUrl = [:]
            dictionaryOfImagesForExport = [:]
            arrayImageForMove = []
            moveArrayImageOfUrl = []
            arrayOfImageUrl2 = []


            self.navigationItem.title = albumName

       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
              dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                let fileManager2 = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
                do {
                    let document = try fileManager2.URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: false)
                    let getFolders = try fileManager2.contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(document, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .SkipsHiddenFiles)

                    for folder in getFolders {
                        if folder.lastPathComponent! == albumName {
                            let getImages = try fileManager2.contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(folder, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .SkipsHiddenFiles)

                            for img in getImages {
                           self.arrayOfImagesFromDocumentDirectory.append(UIImage(contentsOfFile: img.path!)!)
                           self.arrayOfImageUrl2.append(img.path!)

                            }
                        }
                    }

                }catch {
                    print(error)
                }

  self.arrayOfImg = []

                for img in self.arrayOfImagesFromDocumentDirectory {
                    let img2:UIImage = self.ResizeImage(img, targetSize: CGSize(width: 140, height: 140))
                    self.arrayOfImg.append(img2)
                }

                self.myCollectionView.reloadData()


              })


        }
         myCollectionView.reloadData()
    }
```

the following Below MyCode on the `cellForItemAtIndexPath`:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AlbumImagesCollectionViewCell

        if self.dictionaryOfSelectItem.count > 0 {
            if self.dictionaryOfSelectItem[indexPath.row] == indexPath.row {

                cell.imageViewCheck.image = UIImage(named: "check.png")
            }else {
                cell.imageViewCheck.image = nil
            }

        }else {
            cell.imageViewCheck.image = nil
        }


            if self.arrayOfImageUrl2.count > 0  && self.arrayOfImagesFromDocumentDirectory.count > 0 {
                if self.arrayOfImg.count > 0 {
                    cell.imageViewCell.image = self.arrayOfImg[indexPath.row]
                    cell.imageUrlLabel.text = self.arrayOfImageUrl2[indexPath.row]

                }
            }

        return cell

    }
```

any idea for solve my big problem

Thanks Advance

Comment: What is your problem exactly?

Comment: Loading images from document directry to my collectionView is very slow and take lot of memory how can i fetch images fast to my collectionView

Comment: Have you debugged to see where it behaves slow?

Comment: I have photo vault app When i enter to the collectionView i need display the images in collectionView cells fast in my case the images is display to cells take 5 to 7 seconds this is bad for user i hope you are undestanding me

Comment: I understand you, but I want to know if you have identified where the speed problems are. Is it when you load the images? Is it when you assigned to the cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just seen that you are running a background thread but inmediatelly going back the main thread. You need to load the data (images in this case) in the background thread

`dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {`

Also, if you load the images in the `viewDidLoad` instead of in the `viewWillAppear` then you don't need to reload the collection view, because it will load after that and use the data source (in your case `self.arrayOfImg`) to populate.

I also suggest you not to resize the images in the code but use constrains to do that. Please take a look at [Working with Constraints in Interface Builder](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html) from Apple guide.

Is it possible that your images are too big?

Comment: if i put the code in viewDidLoad then i have problem because if i delete any image after the display image the collectionView Not Update it on the new images and i resize the images because my image is too big i have fetch it from photo library using the photos framework

Comment: also i use dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0))  i have wait 5 to 7 second for loading the images to collectionView

Comment: You are using it wrong, because you go back immediately to main thread.

Comment: I guess if your images are too big it will take some time to load all of them if you resize them on the fly, that's may be the reason why is taking so long. What if you use constrains instead?

Comment: what did you mean constraint ? the image in the document directory is big i can't get it on this original size because i get memory warning so i resize the image to width 125.0 height 125.0 when i display it for user and when user select the images from the cell i get the image low resolution so i get the original image from document directory which user select it and resize again to the album

Comment: Please take a look at [Working with Constraints in Interface Builder](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html) from Apple guide.

Comment: It doesn't look wrong, and if it works for you, maybe it's not. You just need to do some fixes. Constrains may help making this faster instead of resizing, but you have to try that and see how it goes.